# Why the class create by Qt creator has no destructor?

Tags: c++, qt

Every time I create a class, there is no destructor in the body of the class? Why is that? The Visual Studio will create a destructor automaticly but the Qt creator doesn't. Is there something special in the class of Qt?

Comment: Your class definitely has a destructor; it's just created by the **compiler** when needed. To create a class without a destructor, you would have to explicitly write `~MyClass = delete`. (This is generally a bad idea - better to delete the constructors instead)

Answer (score 4):

In most well-designed C++ classes you don't need any custom code in the destructor and the default behavior is the right thing (i.e. destroying all members).

You can add a destructor if you want of course and please note that QtCreator mitigates the C++ annoyance of header/implementation duality by allowing automatic creation of the declaration from the implementation or vice versa (e.g. context menu -> refactor -> add public declaration).

Comment: So if we `new` something in constructor, should it be left to garbage collector to clean up? It would be great if you can update the answer in context of creating objects in constructor which is the most common reason we use destructors to clean up.

Comment: @zadane: In modern C++ `new`, especially with naked pointers, is rarely used exactly because you need to take care of the disposal at the appropriate time. If for example you place in your class an `std::vector` nothing is needed in the destructor (and you're not risking a leak if for example an exception gets thrown during the constructor - something that you should be careful about instead if allocating explicitly with `new` because in case of exceptions during the constructor the destructor of the object is NOT invoked).